# Implementing Segment Analytics on Next.js 14 with NextAuth

Tags: next-auth, next.js14, segment-io

I am attempting to implement Segment Analytics on my `Next.js` site.  I am leveraging `NextAuth` for authentication through Google. All of this is working well, but I am now trying to call Segment's [`Identify`](https://segment.com/docs/connections/spec/identify/) method when the user logs in.

However, it does not appear that `NextAuth` emits a client-side event which I can listen for. I have found that I can attach to `events` on the server-side, but that doesn't help me.

`/src/app/api/[...nextauth]/route.js`:

```js
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";

export const authOptions = {
    providers: [
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        }),
    ],
    events: {
        signIn: async (data) => {
            console.log("server-side signIn event detected", data);
        },
    },
};
export const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

Any clever ideas on how I can push this down to the client, or leverage the client-side `useSession` hook to detect this?  I would prefer to not call `identify` on every page load, and only call when the user actually just logged in.

I tried building a client-side function and import it to the server, but got the following error:

> Attempted to call the default export of /SegmentIdentify.js from the server but it's on the client. It's not possible to invoke a client function from the server, it can only be rendered as a Component or passed to props of a Client Component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `signin()` then based on the `NextAuth` docs [about the signIn method](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#using-the-redirect-false-option), you could set `redirect to false` then save the output to a variable. Since `signIn` will then return a `Promise`, that resolves to the following:

```js
{
  /**
   * Will be different error codes,
   * depending on the type of error.
   */
  error: string | undefined
  /**
   * HTTP status code,
   * hints the kind of error that happened.
   */
  status: number
  /**
   * `true` if the signin was successful
   */
  ok: boolean
  /**
   * `null` if there was an error,
   * otherwise the url the user
   * should have been redirected to.
   */
  url: string | null
}
```

You can check if `ok` is `true`, then call the Segment Identify method. After that, you can manually redirect the user to another page if needed.

Comment: this looked super promising, but unfortunately only works for credentials and email providers.  we have to use google in my use case.

https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#using-the-redirect-false-option

Comment: i guess one brute force way could be to:
1. (In next auth signin event: save userId to a kv db or mongodb doc)
2. (In getServerSideProps on page user gets redirected to after signing in: check if the userId exists in the kv db, set a prop that will be passed to the client side (e.g, newSignIn: true), remove the userId from the kv db)
3. (On client side:  in a useEffect, check if prop is true then call Segment Identify method)

Comment: one more method could be to have an AuthButtons component that's dynamically imported with ssr set to false, then when handling the signin click event, set an auth flag to localstorage (e.g isAuth: false), set a useEffect with dep on session, check if session is not undefined && fetch isAuth val from local storage then check if that is false as well. If both conditions are true, it's a new signin then you can call the Segment Identify method & set isAuth to true. Here's an example: [demo](https://github.com/perplexedyawdie/nextauth-google-signin)

Comment: thanks for this.  really appreciate the direction and code sample.

Answer (score 0):

The following approach worked for me:

- Created a grouping of post-login page in my folder structure called (post_logging)
- in (post_logging), i create a layout file, converted it to Client side by using 'use client' on top
- use `import { useSession } from "next-auth/react"` to get the session id, then use `analytics.identify` to identify the user